# How do I calculate the probability of specific dice rolls?

Tags: probability, fractions, dice

My question is a bit simplified due to space constraints, but I'll expand.

Here is my problem: I'm trying to calculate the odds a specific combination of dice. If I roll a die 6 times, what odds of a specific set of rolls. That's an easy enough problem, but the complication is that the numbers I can get on each roll can vary.

For example:

On roll 1, I can get a 1 or a 2
On roll 2, I can get any number but 6
On roll 3, I can only get the number 1
On roll 4, I can get the numbers 1 - 3
Etc...

Now I've been doing this sort of manually. Multiplying the fractions together, to get the odds of it. But it seems like there should be a simpler way, and I just can't figure it out. I've got a bunch of combos to churn through, and will do it manually if I have to, but am trying to save some time!

Forgive my math ignorance, and thanks!

Comment: No simplification can be made. Why do you think that since you have for every roll different conditions ?

Comment: I just mean a simplified way of calculating it.

Comment: You only can put together the denominators to $6^6$. And the numerators can be multiplied separately.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll just work through it

Comment: Do you have many *sets* of possible constraints (where a single set is, for example, "On roll 1, I can get a 1 or a 2 On roll 2, I can get any number but 6 On roll 3, I can only get the number 1 On roll 4, I can get the numbers 1 - 3 Etc..."?  If it is just this single set then you can calculate the probability for each roll individually very easily (for your example, 2/6, 5/6, 1/6, 3/6, etc.) and multiply them since each roll is independent.

Comment: @jagrakye If you included your method then we might be better placed to decide if there was an easier way than you method.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of getting any individual result from a set ${d_1,..,d_n}$ of results from one dice|roll is:
$$
\frac n6
$$

Hence the probability of getting any individual result from a set ${d_{1},..,d_{n_i}}$ for the dice|roll $i$ from 1 to N dices|rolls is:
$$
\prod_{i=1}^N\frac {n_i}6
$$

For example, the probability of getting 1 from dice|roll 1 and 2,3,4 or 5 from dice|roll 2 is ${4 \over 36}$